# How to rerender component based on value from useQuery hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React.js and fetching data using the `useQuery` hook as follows:

```
const { data, isFetching, error } = useGetUserProfileQuery();
```

I was trying the following approach to render a component but failed:

```
{ error !== null ? (<Error openModal={true}/>) : (<Error openModal={false}/>) }
```

Log of error:

```
{
  status: 400,
  data: { error: { status: 400, message: "Only valid bearer authentication supported" } },
};
```

However, it is not triggering the Error component. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting `undefined` when there is no `error`, this `error !== null` check won't work. You could change it to `error !== undefined`  or simply do so:

```
{ error && <Error openModal={true}/> }
```

It's because `undefined` and `null` are not strictly the same thing in JavaScript, as `null` is of type `object` and `undefined` is of type `undefined`. If you had `error != null` with one `=` sign it would work normally as they will get converted to the same type.

```js
console.log(typeof null);
console.log(typeof undefined);
console.log(undefined === null);
console.log(undefined == null);
```

Comment: Hi thank you, it solves the problem. But can i know why is it? or if you can direct me to the right resource. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. It's because `undefined` and `null` are not the same thing in JavaScript.

Comment: i tried using <Error openModal={error !== undefined} /> before, but it is not working the same as the answer you pasted. So that's why I am confusing

Comment: I'm not sure why this `<Error openModal={error !== undefined} />` wouldn't work, but I added an explanation. See my edited code.